# Swift calculate incremental average with reduce and

Tags: swift, average

The propose is to calculate incrementally the average
The code below is the best way I found to calculate incremental average, in order to use it for big numbers and or great array

The following is an example give this array doubles

```
let values = [14.0,12.0, 23.4,37.5,11.46]

var index = 1

let avg = values.reduce(0.0) { return $0 + ( $1 - $0 ) / Double(index++) }
```

avg will be 19.672. and it works.

Is it correct from your point of view?

Is there a way in order to accomplish this with something like:

```
let avg = values.averageIncr()
```

What I don't like is that I have to use and index?

[updated]

a step further, thanks to @Martin R contribute

```
protocol NumericType:Equatable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_ value : Int)
}

extension Double : NumericType { }

extension Array where Element : NumericType {
    mutating func avg_inc_adding( element: Element, var startAvg:Element? = Element(0)  ) throws -> Element{
        if count > 0 && startAvg! == Element(0) {
            startAvg = self.avg_inc()
        }
        append(element)
        return startAvg! + (element - startAvg!) / Element(self.count - 1)
    }
    func avg_inc() -> Element {
        return enumerate().reduce(Element(0)) { $0 + ( $1.1 - $0 ) / Element($1.0 + 1) }
    }
}
```

in this way I'm be able to do something like:

```
var average:Double = values.avg_inc()
do {
    average = try values.avg_inc_adding(34.6,startAvg: z)
}catch {

}
```

that fit with my needs, and I hope with the ones for somebody else.

Comment: Please [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288148/making-my-function-calculate-average-of-array)

Comment: thanks, I will propose this logic with that approach. it should be better

Comment: @Leo: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288148/making-my-function-calculate-average-of-array. This is not a simple average calculation, and OP's problem was that the iteration step involves the current element index. I cannot see how that is addressed in the referenced thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the same result without the need for an "external variable"
with

```
let avg = values.enumerate().reduce(0.0) { $0 + ( $1.1 - $0 ) / Double($1.0 + 1) }
```

because `enumerate()` returns a sequence of index/element pairs.

Implementing that as an extension method is a bit complicated but
possible:

```
protocol NumericType {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_ value : Int)
}

extension Double : NumericType { }

extension Array where Element : NumericType {
    func averageIncr() -> Element {
        return enumerate().reduce(Element(0)) { $0 + ( $1.1 - $0 ) / Element($1.0 + 1) }
    }
}

let avg = values.averageIncr()
```

The `Element` type in an `Array` extension can only restricted to
a *protocol*, not a type. Similarly as in e.g. [What protocol should be adopted by a Type for a generic function to take any number type as an argument in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num) or 
[How can we create a generic Array Extension that sums Number types in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089450/how-can-we-create-a-generic-array-extension-that-sums-number-types-in-swift), you have to define a
protocol which contains all the methods needed in your calculation.

The restriction `Element: FloatingPointType` is not sufficient because
the `FloatingPointType` protocol does not define any arithmetic operations (+, -, /).

---

**Update for Swift 3:** As of Swift 3/Xcode 8, floating point
types conform to the `FloatPoint` protocol and that defines the
arithmetic operations (+, -, /). Therefore a custom protocol is
no longer necessary:

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint {
    func averageIncr() -> Element {
        return enumerated().reduce(Element(0)) { $0 + ( $1.1 - $0 ) / Element($1.0 + 1) }
    }
}
```

Comment: the point is also that enumerate() will add a loop more on the array (I'm looking how enumerate() works right now) and this slow down performance if the array has a big numbers of elements

Comment: @tylyo: Both your original code and my suggested extension method (using enumerate) compute the incremental average of an array with 1,000,000 random numbers in about 0.008 seconds on my computer. There is no significant difference in the performance.

Comment: is `Element(0)` meant to be something generic so that if it was `Int` it would do `Int(0)`...if `Double` it would `Double(0)` and initialize to its type?

Comment: @Honey: `Element(0)` calls the `init(_ value : Int)` method which is required in the `NumericType` protocol. Add floating point types have such a `init(_ value : Int)` method. – But the custom protocol is no longer necessary with Swift 3, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MartinR @Honey:  *add floating point types have such a `init(_ value : Int)` method.* what? Element(0) calls `init ( _ value : Int) while Element(0.0) calls `init (_ value Float)`

Comment: @Honey: No, `$1.0` is an integer as well: The offset/index from the enumerated() method.

Comment: You mean it's a tuple?!

Comment: @Honey: `enumerated()` returns a sequence of `(index, element)` tuples.